# MacOS terminal command 'python3 file.py' goes into directory instead of executing script file from PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal, path

I added a custom PATH in .bash_profile and I wanted to run a script file without cd-ing to the directory.

However, when I try to use `python3 gmail.py` or `python gmail.py` in terminal, it gives me the following error:
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3: can't open file 'gmail.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I have Anaconda & Python 3.8 installed on top of the Python 2.7 comes vanilla with MacOS. I suspect when I type in python3 it searches under the Python 3 folder directory instead of recognizing it as a run-file command.

My .bash_profile looks like this:

```
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/stevenwang/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/stevenwang/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/stevenwang/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/stevenwang/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
export PATH=${PATH}:/desktop/script/
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Did I make an error in setting up my PATH or is there a conflict in terminal commands?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

That’s just not what `PATH` does; moreover, there is no environment variable that Python searches.  Normally you put a wrapper **shell** script that knows the location of the script on your `PATH`.